# Custom Error Page para aplicacion web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

Estoy tratando de ante cualquier error 500, 404, 403 o 400 me redireccione a la vista cshtml personalizada.

[image: Views]

Cree un controller

[image: Controller]

Agregue lo siguiente en web.config

[image: webconfig]

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

[image: error]

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: ok colocaste todo eso de custom error pero en la accion agregaste [HandleError]  ?  revisa el codigo de este proyecto [mvc5 errors](https://github.com/olsh/mvc5-custom-error-pages-example)

Comment: En cada accion que pueda generar error deberia agregar un handleerror? Ya que esto seria tedioso

Comment: Lo puedes agregar como filtro generico o a nivel clase, o incluso crear una clase  controller base.

Comment: Ahi lo agregue sobre errorcontroller, acabo de editar el post para que puedas ver si hay algun error.